# Tkinter entry insert from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning a bit of tkinter at the moment and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve.

I have 1 class (named 'GUI') in which I first declare an object of another class (named 'client') then create a simple tkinter GUI with an entry field in which the user enters an address.

I then have a button that when pressed, gets the address and passes it to a function of the client class. This function calls another function from a library, which goes out to an external source (the 'client') and gets the value of a boolean register at that address.

Up to here I have working.

I now would like to update another entry field in the tkinter GUI with the value of that Boolean register.

Here is a code sample:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        device = client()
        self.master = master
        #Define size (x,y) and position (top left is 0,0) of window
        master.geometry("800x400+300+300")
        #Disable window resize
        master.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        #GUI Controls
        lbl_read_discrete_output = Label(self.master, text="Read boolean register")
        lbl_read_discrete_output_address = Label(self.master, text="Address:")
        ent_read_discrete_output_address = Entry(self.master)
        btn_read_discrete_output_address = Button(self.master, text='READ', command=lambda: device.read_discrete_output(int(ent_read_discrete_output_address.get())))
        ent_read_discrete_output_value = Entry(self.master, state='disabled')

        #GUI Layout
        lbl_read_discrete_output.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=5, pady=5)
        lbl_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
        ent_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=2, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
        ent_read_discrete_output_value.grid(column=3, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)

class client:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_discrete_output(self, address):
    data = self._client.read_coils(address-1, 1).bits[0:1]
    if not data[0]:
        #Update entry field 'ent_read_discrete_output_value' with "FALSE"
    else:
        #Update entry field 'ent_read_discrete_output_value' with "TRUE"

def main():
    #Create GUI object
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make the entry widget an attribute of the class that is public. Then access it from outside the class.

Comment: Hi Eshita, thanks for that. I am still fairly new to python, are you able to show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that problem, this way:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master

    #GUI Controls
    lbl_read_discrete_output = Label(self.master, text="Read boolean register")
    lbl_read_discrete_output_address = Label(self.master, text="Address:")
    self.ent_read_discrete_output_address = Entry(self.master)
    btn_read_discrete_output_address = Button(self.master, text='READ', command=lambda: device.read_discrete_output(int(self.ent_read_discrete_output_address.get())))
    self.ent_read_discrete_output_value = Entry(self.master, state='disabled')

    #GUI Layout
    lbl_read_discrete_output.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=5, pady=5)
    lbl_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.ent_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
    btn_read_discrete_output_address.grid(column=2, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.ent_read_discrete_output_value.grid(column=3, row=7, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.x=self.ent_read_discrete_output_address.get()
    print(self.x) 
    device=clientx(self.ent_read_discrete_output_value,self.ent_read_discrete_output_address.get())

class clientx():
    def __init__(self,ent,address):
    self.address=address
    self.ent=ent
    def read_discrete_output(self, address):
        with ModbusClient('127.0.0.1') as client:
            data = self.client.read_coils(address-1, 1).bits[0:1]

        if not data[0]:
            self.ent.config(state="disabled")
        else:
            self.ent.config(state="disabled")

def main():
    #Create GUI object
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Wow, you figured out that I am using pymodbus (I tried to leave it out to simplify the question), very impressive! Your code is a little different to how I am actually implementing but hopefully with a bit of massaging I can get it to function. I will get back to you! Thankyou!

Comment: Yes. You should include the libraries used when, asking a question.
My pleasure helping..